# Failed to import Tensorflow in Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've installed CPU version of Tensorflow on the Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x64 on the Windows 10 with the following sequence of commands:

```
conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.6
activate tensorflow
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

and no errors occured. But then I've tried to import Tensorflow and the following text appeared

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module(mname)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I've checked out some similar questions here and I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `conda install tensorflow` instead of `pip`

For installations within `anaconda` virtual environments its preferable to use `conda install package_name`

or switch back to **version <1.6** i.e `pip install tensorflow==1.5`

Solution reference : [GitHub-TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17393)